# aurelia browser loading main.ts not main.js

Tags: aurelia

i am new to aurelia, and when including it into my project as the api frontend i ran into an issue i need clarification about.

i followed the basic [starting guide](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start) and made sure the code could load. which it does if i name the `main.js` as `main.ts` (and `app.js` also).

due to the fact, that i did not find any explanation or configuation option in the code nor "the internet" i wonder what i did do wrong

does someone else did have that problem.

it tries to load typescript even though the documentation says app.js there

### Minimal Project

1. download http://aurelia.io/downloads/basic-aurelia-project.zip
2. copy the code in http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start as js
3. run any webserver with it. (e.g. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`)

Comment: I'm a little unsure what your issue is? You say it does load if you name the files correctly? [Look here to see how to write a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you have opted for the "Typescript" version of the startup project from aurelia - .ts files are for this language which is not exactly javascript. If you want to use the javascript approach choose for example the esnext project.

Comment: @Ovidiu Dolha: can you elaborate? i am not aware that there is any setting to be made in that download or quick-start documentation

Comment: From docs: **If you look at the second script tag, you will see its src pointing to scripts/config-typescript.js. This is the configuration for TypeScript. So, if you want to use TypeScript, you are all set and don't need to make any changes. If you want to use ESNext, you need to swap its src so that it points at scripts/config-esnext.js.

That's it. Your language selection is now configured with these docs and with your new project.** So basically default is TypeScript where your source files should be *.ts, but you can easily change it by loading a different script in index.html

Comment: @Ovidiu Dolha 
thanks. there is a documentation example mismatch then. 
"Ok, we're almost ready to run our app. The next piece is to tell Aurelia how it should render **app.js;**" 
i did not assume they deliberately set the download up to fail

Comment: @Ovidiu Dolha 
i am certainly not the only one who would overread that subtle pale text there. please add it as an answer for others too

Comment: yes, could be a bit misleading. Aurelia intro / startup documentation had suffered some changes during its development and there are more than one valid starting points, so there could still be glitches - but they do have an open policy and accept change proposals in the form of pull requests on their doc repo (see edit button on the top) - so you could theoretically submit a clarification

Comment: yea, i looked at that ...  the most simple "clearification" would be to set up the download to use js in the first place and have a code listing with html for TS and html for ES at that place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The startup package is configured by default to work with TypeScript so to change this you need to replace the script

```
<script src="scripts/config-typescript.js"></script>
```

in `index.html` with

```
<script src="scripts/config-esnext.js"></script>
```

to use Javascript / ES next

This is mentioned in the documentation but may be easily missed, and the rest of the startup documentation follows the javascript approach.

Note that this tutorial is a quick startup - a more comprehensive one is http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial and some more alternative seeds (e.g. JSPM / webpack) can be found in this repo: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation